# Proof by induction of $\sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)(k)\binom{n}{k} = n(n-1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I've been struggling with this sum for an while, plugging $n+1$ instead of $n$, knowing that $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}$  and after some manipulation  I've found this sum.
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2\binom{n}{k}$$
I couldn't see any way I could get out of here and I don't know how to start this proof without the property of the sum of binomial coefficients.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "after some manipulation i've found this sum."... So you've solved the problem but are wondering if there was a way to do it without knowing $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}$? Or, have you found the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: Well, if the proof is by induction I was supposed to find $n(n+1)2^{n-1}$ as a result of pluggin in $n+1$ instead of $n$ am I right? Instead I found $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k}$ and I can't progress from now on.

Comment: hmmm i just need to make

$$\sum^{i+1}_{k=2}{{n-2}\choose{k-2}}=2^{n-2}$$.....then i should have an answer for you

Comment: you say that but theres no gaurentee im anywhere near right....but hey! thats the fun of maths stack eh

Comment: Oh shiiii.... I forgot something. There's a 2 multiplying the sum so it actually is $2 \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}$. I'll fix that in the post.

Comment: just to make sure ive got it right. you want an inductive proof of  
$$\sum^{n}_{k=2}(k-1)(k){{n}\choose{k}}=n(n-1)2^{n-2}$$ right?

Comment: Counting proof: Select a team (of at least 2 members) with a captain and a vice-captain.

Comment: posted what i have, hope that helps.

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k-1)(k)\binom{n+1}{k} = 1.2\binom{n+1}{2} + 2.3\binom{n+1}{3} +...+ (n+1)n\binom{n+1}{n} + n(n+1)\binom{n+1}{n+1} = 2\binom{n}{1} + [2(1+3)]\binom{n}{2} + [3(2+4)]\binom{n}{3} +...+ [(n-1)(2n-2)]\binom{n}{n+1} + n(2n) = 2\bigl(\binom{n}{1} + 2^2\binom{n}{2} +...+ (n-1)^2\binom{n}{n-1} + n^2\binom{n}{n}\bigl) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2\binom{n}{k}$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want any proof or specifically a proof by induction, but here is a proof.

Recall that $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k x^k = (1+x)^n$ by the binomial theorem. Then, differentiating both sides twice with respect to $x$, we find that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)\binom{n}k x^k = n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}. 
$$
Then, plugging in $x=1$ will give you the desired result.

Comment: And from here, we can find \begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2\binom{n}{k} &= \sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)\binom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} \\ &= n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1} \\ &= n(n+1)2^{n-2} \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to forgive me if I've misunderstood something but assuming $$\sum^{n}_{k=2}(k-1)(k){{n}\choose{k}}=n(n-1)2^{n-2}$$ is the requirement for the inductive proof then here I go.

Using the identity

$$i{{n}\choose{i}}=n{{n-1}\choose{i-1}}$$ we have

$$\sum^{n}_{k=2}(k-1)(k){{n}\choose{k}}=n(n-1)2^{n-2} \Rightarrow$$
$$n\sum^{n}_{k=2}(k-1){{n-1}\choose{k-1}}=n(n-1)2^{n-2}\Rightarrow$$
$$n(n-1)\sum^{n}_{k=2}{{n-2}\choose{k-2}}=n(n-1)2^{n-2}$$

This means we just need to prove inductively that 
$$\sum^{n}_{k=2}{{n-2}\choose{k-2}}=2^{n-2}$$ which is apparently a rewriting of
$$(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}x^{n-k}y^{k}$$ where $x$ and $y$ are both set to $1$.

Comment: "apparently"... ok, the $n$ in the last equation would also be $n-2$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combinatorial proof.

We count committees of $k$ people with a chairperson and a vice-chairperson selected from a group with $n$ people in two ways.

To form a committee of size $k$ with a chairperson and a vice-chairperson, we can first choose $k$ of the $n$ people to serve on the committee, then select one of those $k$ people to serve as the chairperson, and one of the remaining $k - 1$ people to serve as the vice-chairperson.  The number of ways to do this is 
$$k(k - 1)\binom{n}{k}$$
The summation on the left-hand side counts all such committees.

Alternatively, we can select one of the $n$ people to be the chairperson, one of the remaining $n - 1$ people to be the vice-chairperson, and then choose a subset of the remaining $n - 2$ people to serve on the committee with them.  Since there are $2^{n - 2}$ subsets of a set with $n - 2$ elements, the number of ways this can be done is 
$$n(n - 1)2^{n - 2}$$

Since both sides of the equation count the same set of committees, we may conclude that 
$$\sum_{k = 2}^{n} k(k - 1)\binom{n}{k} = n(n - 1)2^{n - 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Applying Pascal's identity gives you
$$ \sum_k k(k - 1) \binom{n + 1}{k} = \sum_k k(k - 1) \binom{n}{k} + \sum_k k(k - 1) \binom{n}{k - 1}. $$

If we call the sum $f(n)$ then this says that

$$ f(n + 1) = f(n) + \text{ a sum that looks very much like } f(n). \tag{1}$$

We can deal with the second sum by changing variables:

$$ \sum_k k(k - 1) \binom{n}{k - 1} = \sum_k (k + 1)k \binom{n}{k} = f(n) + 2\sum_k k \binom{n}{k}. \tag{2}$$

Let $g(n) = \sum_k k \binom{n}{k}$. Then similarly we find that

$$ g(n + 1) = g(n) + \sum_k (k + 1) \binom{n}{k} = 2g(n) + \sum_k \binom{n}{k} = 2g(n) + 2^n. $$

Therefore
\begin{align}
g(n + 1) &= 2g(n) + 2^n \\
&= 2\left[2g(n - 1) + 2^{n - 1} \right] + 2^n \\
&= 4g(n - 1) + 2 \cdot 2^n \\
&= 8g(n - 2) + 3 \cdot 2^n \\
\end{align}
and by induction
$$g(n + 1) = 2^{n + 1}g(0) + (n + 1)2^n = (n + 1)2^n. \tag{3}$$

Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ gives us

$$ f(n + 1) = 2f(n) + 2g(n) = 2f(n) + n2^n. $$

Hence induction gives

$$ f(n + 1) = n2^n + (n - 1)2^n + (n - 2)2^n + \dots + 1 \cdot 2^n = n(n + 1)2^{n - 1}. $$

Answer (score 0):

A proof by induction seems to be somewhat cumbersome. The essence in the answer of @Vaas is the relationship
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}\binom{n-2}{k-2}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Using (1) we obtain for $n\geq 2$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}}&=n(n-1)\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n-2}{k-2}\\
> &=n(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=n(n-1)2^{n-2}}
> \end{align*}

In (2) we shift the index $k$ to start from $k=0$ and are ready to apply the binomial theorem.